# How to add data to the end of a CSV file (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I need to be able to periodically add data to the end of a CSV file. Ideally, I would like to do this without reading the entire file into memory.

Is there a way where I can append data to the end of a file?. One solution that occured to me was to simply shell a pipe command from Python, but that seemed too much of an ugly hack. is there a better way to append a line or maybe a few lines to the end of a CSV file?

Comment: Sometimes (to write to Excel-compatible CSV's) it's `open(fname,'ab')`.

Comment: Ah yes, its always the obvious ones that you miss. I can't belive how obvious the answer is. I can either ask for this question to be closed or either one of you guys can answer so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are two approaches. First, you can just `open(filename, 'ab')`, which will open the file for [appending in binary mode](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). The second is using [seek](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek):

```
import os
my_file = open("data.csv", "ab")
my_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

(I threw that second one in there mainly so I wasn't just ripping off S. Lott and SilentGhost. It's not particularly useful.)

Comment: Erm, unless I'm mistaken, you can't append to a file opened in read mode? - am I missing something here?

Comment: According to that tutorial link: "`r+` opens the file for both reading and writing". According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), it's for "updating." Um...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Probably stick to 'ab' mode just to make sure the data gets appended.

Comment: @skyeagle - honestly, I have no idea what it means by "updating." I'd use 'ab' too (changing answer now).